# Start lodash fp pipe or compose with fixed arity bigger than 1

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

Having this two arrays

```js
const segmentIds = ['segmentId1', 'segmentId2' ]
const storiesBySegment = [['storyId1', 'storyId2'], ['storyId3', 'storyId4']]
```

I want to `zip` them, so I have a final version like this:

```js
// zippedSegments = [['segmentId1', ['storyId1', 'storyId2']], ...]
```

With imperative lodash you got `_.zip(segmentIds, storiesBySegment)`
But I don’t know how to do it in `FP` AND in a pipe.

I tried this for example, but no luck.

```js
const fp = require('lodash/fp')

const segmentIds = ['segmentId1', 'segmentId2' ]
const storiesBySegment = [['storyId1', 'storyId2'], ['storyId3', 'storyId4']]

const segmentFP = fp.pipe(
   fp.zip(segmentIds)(storiesBySegment)
)(segmentIds, storiesBySegment)
```

I can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: What's `fp`? Maybe share the reference of your lib?

Comment: Edited ('lodash/fp')

Answer (score -2):

Ok I'm stupid, I was invoking the function instead of passing it as an argument.

So it would look like this:

```js
const segmentFP = fp.pipe(
   fp.zip
)(segmentIds, storiesBySegment)
```